# jquery UI slider with a range that starts at a specific value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

It's probably easier if I just show an example of what I want to do.  I found a demo at http://fiddle.jshell.net/g33ky/DxK5m/3/show/light/

In short, I want the a color range to appear from a specific value (e.g. middle of the slider bar) to the current selected sliderbar position.  As far as I can tell, jquery-ui's range option for sliders only support ranges from the min and max values of the slider bar.

I believe the demo above is actually changing the code for jquery slider.  I don't mind doing that, but I cannot get it to work properly outside of jsfiddle.  I've tried saving the code directly from using view source and it will still only on jsfiddle.  I would really appreciate it if someone can tell me how to make the code from the above demo work outside of jsfiddle, or if someone can show me how to get a slider to do the same thing using jquery or pure javascript.  Thanks in advance.  I've pulled so much hair out over this, my scalp hurts!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but you can set the position of the slider handle by setting it's "value" property.

```
$("#slider").slider({
  value: 30,
  ... other properties ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid you did misunderstand.  Not only do I want the value to be set at 30, I also want to use the "range" option so that the range is not from min or max (currently the acceptable values for the range attribute).  I need the range to be from the set value (say 30 in your example) to the current slider position.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case that's not clear, what I mean by range is the area shown in red when you drag the slider around at http://fiddle.jshell.net/g33ky/DxK5m/3/show/light/

The problem with that demo is that the same source doesn't seem to work outside of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="sliderContend_h" style="padding-top:10px;">

 <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="15" min="15" max="25"  class="slider_h" data-highlight="true" />

                     </div>
```

Comment: That didn't do what I need.  It just gave me a slider.  It didn't address the range color issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers posted.  I figured out a way to do it after all.  If anyone else is looking to do the same thing, I was able to modify Dragdealer (available at http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/) to achieve the effect I wanted.